# How can I perform a conditional indirect sum in excel with an if function?

Tags: excel, vba, match, substitution, excel-indirect

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P0k0CBFRf2DQfv9RSOVjlQ1UtG6wenjY11qRjTqAxsM/edit?usp=sharing)

Profit

[image: Profit]

Sales

[image: Sales]

Expenses

[image: Expenses]

COGS

[image: COGS]

Hello, I have an array of financial data that I need to turn into profit. I have been able to successfully sum all of the financial together based on a specific date range, but I have encountered a problem with cost of goods sold. Using the match function (apologies if the format is ridiculous, I am new to stackoverflow; the formula is present in the google sheet as well):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sales'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"") &MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)))+SUM(INDIRECT("'Expenses'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,Expenses!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Expenses!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,Expenses!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Expenses!A:A,0)))+SUM(INDIRECT("'COGS'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,COGS!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,COGS!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,COGS!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Expenses!A:A,0)))
```

I can sum every value on every sheet by row when matching a list of IDs which is constant throughout all data sheets. My problem is: I only want to sum the cost of goods sold sheet to profit ONLY If there is a corresponding sales value in the same location but on the sales tab. Ive tried replacing the sum with sumif to no avail, as I am just getting the hang of this indirect functions. Can anyone provide me with any information that may help me better understand this problem I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Im sorry but I think I still need some more clarification. You have 4 tabs, so you want to find the position of the corresponding ID on these tabs, and only when on tab Sales it is actually any value other then empty you want to sum all these values? Im just confused since on the sample data you added, cell C3 on profit tab seems to be different.

Comment: Correct; so for the sample data, there will never be an instance where a sale will not have a corresponding expense; however, regardless of whether there is a sale or not, there will be a cost of goods sold value. for cell B3 (profit for ID 123 from 1/1/19 to 1/6/19) if i were to sum up all values on the three sheets for that date range, the profit would be 1.6; however, since ID123 did not have sales on 1/3-1/6, i dont want it to add the COGS for 1/3-1/6, only 1/1 and 1/2 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info I can only come up with that.

`=SUM(Sales!B2:I2)+SUM(Expenses!B2:I2)-SUMPRODUCT((Sales!B2:I2<>0)*(COGS!B2:I2))`

or

`=SUMPRODUCT((Sales!B2:I2)*($C$1<=Sales!B1:I1)*($E$1>=Sales!B1:I1))+SUMPRODUCT((Expenses!B2:I2)*($C$1<=Expenses!B1:I1)*($E$1>=Expenses!B1:I1))-SUMPRODUCT((Sales!B2:I2<>0)*(COGS!B2:I2)*($C$1<=COGS!B1:I1)*($E$1>=COGS!B1:I1))`

if dates matters

With the sheet you provided it returns 3.2

Why did you used so much `indirect` & `substitute`?

Was it required or fixed ranged fits your need ?

Comment: I believe `SOMMEPROD` is actually `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: Indeed Thanks. Had kept it in french.

Comment: So I need it to sum by row based on the date condition.. ex., for ID 123 over the date range (1/1-1/6) the first part of the formula sums every sale from 1/1-1/6 (3+7+0+0+0+0), the second does the same for expenses (-2+-4+0+0+0+0) and the third does the same for cogs (-.4+-.4+-.4+-.4+-.4+-.4). the formula I'm looking for would do everything the same except the COGS portion, as I would not be evaluating profit for a specific day as -.4 if there was no corresponding sale. Unfortunately the COGS data source does not discriminate and places the COGS value on the sheet everyday regardless of sales.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((Sales!B2:I2)*($C$1<=Sales!B1:I1)*($E$1>=Sales!B1:I1))+SUMPRODUCT((Expenses!B2:I2)*($C$1<=Expenses!B1:I1)*($E$1>=Expenses!B1:I1))-SUMPRODUCT((Sales!B2:I2<>0)*(COGS!B2:I2)*($C$1<=COGS!B1:I1)*($E$1>=COGS!B1:I1))

This one takes dates into account

Answer (score 0):

I think that the COGS was meant to be a one time expense per day. That is how all but the first example are calculated. 
If so, I believe the correct answer is:

```
{=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sales'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)))+SUM(INDIRECT("'Expenses'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,Expenses!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Expenses!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,Expenses!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Expenses!A:A,0)))+SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sales'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0))/INDIRECT("'Sales'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,Sales!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Sales!A:A,0)),0),INDIRECT("'COGS'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,COGS!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,COGS!A:A,0)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($E$1,COGS!$1:$1,0),4),1,"")&MATCH(A3,Expenses!A:A,0)))}
```